# TypeScript importing prevents intellisense/autocomplete when using lodash definition stubs in WebStorm/IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, webstorm, lodash, definitelytyped

I've noticed that when importing lodash after already referencing the definition file, WebStorm loses all the code intelligence it gains when referencing this definition file.

The code looks something like

```
/// <reference path="lodash.d.ts" />
import _ = require('lodash');
```

v.s.

```
/// <reference path="lodash.d.ts" />
```

Both examples will compile just fine, so it does not affect the compiler.

For the record, I'm using the [DefinitelyTyped Lodash definition file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/lodash.d.ts).

Some screenshots that demonstrate what I mean:

[image: Example without import]
<sub>(source: [nath.is](http://c.nath.is/V97W/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-23%20at%2011.32.05.png))</sub>

[image: Example with import]
<sub>(source: [nath.is](http://c.nath.is/V9OI/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-23%20at%2011.32.png))</sub>

I'm using the AMD module option. This is my File Watcher.

[image: File Watcher]
<sub>(source: [nath.is](http://c.nath.is/V8rW/Image%202014-04-23%20at%2011.50.41%20am.png))</sub>

Also, the module is definitely installed in my node_modules folder.

Comment: repeatable for me in WebStorm 8.0.1; works fine in current daily build (136.1746)

Comment: Is there anyway to easily update to this daily build?

Comment: Also does that mean that it is a bug in WebStorm?

Comment: sure it's a bug that is fixed in next WebStorm version

Comment: I have WebStorm 9.0.2 and IntelliSense is working fine with both `import` and `///<reference...`

Comment: @GáborImre Please post that comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I have WebStorm 9.0.2 and IntelliSense is working fine both with `import` and with `///<reference...`